# could not connect to Tor control port on MacOS X El Captain

Tags: mac

tried re-install, still doesn't work
and it copies 0 Tor log...so i got nothing to show here...
when the error message "could not connect to Tor control port" pops up, there's nothing else i can do except for clicking "OK", then "Quit"
what's wrong? Anyone help?